# Eating Saturated Fat along with Carbs in LCHF Diet

Tags: ketogenic-diet, low-carb

I was doing keto diet for 3 months and I had to quite because of the keto rash. I wanna do Low-Carb-High-Fat (LCHF) with 100-120 grams of carbs, something like (60,30,30) for (fat,protein,crabs) but my concern is how to eat those carbs? I mean, based on my understanding, eating carbs will raise insulin spikes, so the odds to store the (saturated) fat is increased. Should I separate the fat from carbs meals? For example, I eat two meals per day, is it healthy to do a "fat" meal and a "carb" meal?

I found that some of the Paelo diet people do the same portions, however, I don't attend to follow the Paelo diet such as not eating cheese, etc. Is this healthy from LCHF perspective? I don't want to harm myself by eating more (saturated) fat and not being in ketosis.

Can I lose weight if my macros are deficient using this diet?